# Set order of RSpec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm building a test suite to teach OOP. I want the files in my `spec/lib` folder to be executed in a specific order.

I would like to define an array of class names, and their test suite would be executed in order. For example:

```
spec_order = %w(
  FirstClass
  SecondClass
  ThirdClass
)
```

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: Figured out that naming the spec files: `01_first_spec.rb`, `02_second_spec.rb`, `03_third_spec.rb`, and adding the `--order defined` flag seems to give me the desired results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Name the `_spec.rb` files numerically:

```
01_first_spec.rb
02_second_spec.rb
...
```

Create a `.rspec` file

```
# .rspec

--order defined
```

Now, when running `rspec` the files should be executed in sorted order.

Answer (score 2):

Ordering tests is **not recommended** by almost all testing frameworks. That is part of making sure that tests are independent and don't yield unexpected behavior when order changes.

However, if you want to run test files in specific order then you can accomplish that by writing scripts:

### 1. Shell Script

Consider the following script (ordered_test_script.sh):

```
for f in file1_spec.rb file2_spec.rb file3_spec.rb
do
  rspec $f
done
```

Make sure the script is executable:

```
chmod +x ordered_test_script.sh
```

Then you can run the script:

```
./ordered_test_script.sh
```

### 2. Ruby Script

First, you might want to extend the String class to include an underscore method:

```
class String
  def underscore
    self.gsub(/::/, '/').
    gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
    gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
    tr("-", "_").
    downcase
  end
end
```

This will turn camelcase class names to underscore ones. For example (MyClass => my_class)

```
classes = %w(MyClass1 MyClass2 MyClass3)

classes.each do |c|
  system("rspec #{c.to_s.underscore}_spec.rb")
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very aware that the order of tests should not be important. In this case, it has to do with introducing concepts in a particular order.

Comment: are the classes you want to test in-order separated in different spec files?

Comment: yes, each class/rspec test represents a separate concept

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's good practice to have randomization by default, but in some cases, such as when trying to track down order-related issues in your specs, or for documentation generation, it might be nice to specify a temporary order.

You can specify a "global" ordering for some (or all) of your spec files as follows:

```
config.register_ordering(:global) do |items|
  files = <<END.split("\n")
./spec/some_spec.rb
./spec/another_spec.rb
END
  # Original RSpec random order
  randomized = RSpec::Core::Ordering::Random.new(config).order(items)

  # Now do a stable sort by filename index
  randomized.sort_by.with_index do |example_group, index|
    files.index(example_group.file_path) || files.size + index
  end
end
```

Documentation for `register_ordering` is available [on Relish](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/overriding-global-ordering).